# Why is my onclick inPug not calling my js function?

Tags: node.js, express, button, onclick, pug

I am attempting to call a function in my js file from the html side. Currently, I am using PUG my for templating engine and cannot get the onclick to work.

Views/client.js

```
function doSomething() {
  alert("Just work");
}
```

Views/customize.pug

```
button(onclick='doSomething()') fail
    <script src='client.js'></script>
```

If I copy over my function to customize.pug. And add it in using

```
script.
function doSomething() {
  alert("Just work");
}
```

It works just fine. However, I can never call the function in client.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using express, your client-side javascript should be in a public directory exposed using `express.static`. Your `client.js` in the `Views` directory is not directly accessible without a explicit route.

You can expose the entire public directory in app.js/index.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Place the client.js as `public/javascripts/client.js`

And in your `Views/customize.pug` you can include it

```
button(onclick='doSomething()') fail
script(src='/javascripts/client.js')
```

Comment: Thank you, I spent way too much time on this issue and really appreciate the help.